# How to load gtag.js (Google analytics) dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I am trying to block google analytics in javascript when a user don't want to get cookies.

```
if (want_cookie != "no"){
   /* load google analytics script */
 }
```

But I didn't find how to load this script in javascript ...

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX');
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    if (want_cookie != "no"){
        var newScript = document.createElement("script");
            newScript.type = "text/javascript";
            newScript.setAttribute("async", "true");
            newScript.setAttribute("src", "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX");
            document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

So what I did is after checking if user agree on cookies dynamically create script element and append it to page.

Comment: This seems to replace the first `<script>` but what about the second one?

Comment: beware, `document.documentElement.firstChild` does not necessarily refer to the `<head>`element!

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of the accepted answer, I implemented it like this:

HTML:

```
<button id="declineButton">Decline</button>
<button id="acceptButton">Accept</button>
```

JS for declining:

```
declineButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window["ga-disable-G-XXXX"] = true; // replace G-XXXX with your id
});
```

JS for accepting:

```
acceptButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window["ga-disable-G-XXXX"] = false; // replace G-XXXX with your id
  appendScriptToHead();
  executeGoogleAnalyticsScript();
});

function appendScriptToHead() {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.async = true;
  script.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXX"; // replace G-XXXX with your ID
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

function executeGoogleAnalyticsScript() {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag("js", new Date());
  gtag("config", "G-XXXX"); // replace G-XXXX with your id
}
```

Note:
According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out) we have to make sure that the disabling (setting the window property) is done before the `gtag()` is executed.